# Can't find gtags layer default key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, ctags, spacemacs, exuberant-ctags

I was trying to include the Gtags layer to make use of it in my spacemacs setup like I learned to do with vim+ctags in a given project.

Followed the instructions from: https://www.spacemacs.org/layers/+tags/gtags/README.html and included the layer in my ~/.spacemacs 'dotspacemacs-configuration-layers'. But even after restarting it I could not find the 'SPC m' key bindings to use its features.

I also tried setting (gtags :variables gtags-enable-by-default t) to have it enabled by default but apparently it did not work as well.

How do I get access to those 'SPC m' key bindings?

[No 'm' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrdUb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did not find a way to solve my *gtags* issue, but found another solution using *etags-select*.
As long as I do generate my TAGS file using the *"-e"* flag to be Emacs compatible, then I can navigate using tags.

```
cd /path/to/my/project
ctags -e -R .
```

It solved the my issue :)